# Data not reloading on history redirect to a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a sweetalert update component, which update certain information and than redirect user to a different route if updation of data results in success. Everything works fine but the problem is on redirection through **useHistory()** the component where user is redirected do no update the changes made in the data.

Here is my update component code which update the data on submit event

```js
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Fire confirmation
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      showDenyButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: `Yes`,
      denyButtonText: `No`,
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        updateNotes();
        history.push('/notes');
      } else if (result.isDenied) {
        Swal.fire('Notes not updated!', '', 'info');
      }
    });
  };

  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
  async function updateNotes() {
    bodyFormData.append('description', notesData.description);

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
      body: bodyFormData,
    };
    fetch(URL, requestOptions)
      .then(async (response) => {
        const data = await response.json();
        // check for error response
        if (!response.ok) {
          const error = (data && data.message) || response.status;
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        Swal.fire('Notes updated successfully', '', 'success');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire('Error updating notes', '', 'error');
      });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And here is my notes component where the user is redirected, This component fetch when component loads

```js
// fetch notes
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(fetchURL, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } })
      .then((response) => {
        // If request is good...
        if (response) {
          if (!response.data[response.data.length - 1].has_next) setNext(0);
          setNotes(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error('Something went wrong, please refresh');
        console.log(error);
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [fetchURL]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In short i want to run this fetch method everytime component renders or **fetchURL** state modifies.

Please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: When you mean everytime component renders does it mean when it mounts?.
You can extract the fetching in another function and do this
`useEffect(() => { fetch here on mount}, [])` and `useEffect(() => { fetch here on url change}, [fetchUrl])`

Comment: Yes I mean the same, so I need to write two different use effect to fetch data or there is any other different possible solution.